# cocoa calendar control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I found great cocoa calendar control at googlecode — http://code.google.com/p/calendarcontrol/ . Looks great , but unfortunately i can't build sources of example project. I've try resolve dependencies problem with amber.framework for several hours, but no success. Does anyone tried this control?
Maybe someone have fully read build&go example?

Comment: Please post the output in the build log from the first failed step.

Comment: i made this steps: 1. `svn checkout http://calendarcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ calendarcontrol-read-only`  2. download "amber.framework" follow the link in "Using the Control" section on googlecode site 3. add framework to the example project (Add->Existing framework) 4. Trying to compile, and it give me this errors - "AmberFoundation/AmberFoundation.h - no such file or directory ; CoreAmberKit/CoreAmberKit.h - no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Please read index poge of the site you put here

> Blockquote
>   CalendarControl is dependent on a framework (AmberKitAdditions) contained inside another one of my projects Amber found at http://code.google.com/p/amber-framework which must be available at compile time.